# XPath to select tags near (before and after) another element?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

It is possible to select all `br` tags before and after an `h3` element with XPath?

This selects only the first `br` tag: `//h3/following-sibling::*[1][name()='br']`

Here is a code snippet, I would like to select the 2 `br` tags before and the 2 `br` tags after the `h3` tag:

```
<br />22111 Hamburg<br />(U- und Busbahnhof Billstedt)<br /><br /><h3>Wir treffen uns</h3><br /><br />um Erfahrungen auszutauschen...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Notes:**

1. You probably don't mean *all* `h3` elements but rather one
   particular `h3` element.
2. `[1]` is causing only the next following sibling to be selected.
3. Rather than `*[name()='br']`, use `br`.
4. Be sure you mean `following-sibling`, not `following`.

**Then this XPath,**

```
//h3[.='Heading']/following-sibling::br
```

**will select all `br` elements are siblings to the `h3` element whose string value is `Heading`.**

---

### Update

For this HTML,

```
<div>
   <br/>22111 Hamburg<br/>
   (U- und Busbahnhof Billstedt)
   <br/><br/>
   <h3>Wir treffen uns</h3>
   <br/><br/>
   um Erfahrungen auszutauschen...
   <br/>abc<br/>
</div>
```

this XPath will select the two `br` sibling elements immediately *before* the targeted `h3`,

```
//h3[.='Wir treffen uns']/preceding-sibling::br[position() < 3]
```

this XPath will select the two `br` sibling elements immediately *after* the targeted `h3`,

```
//h3[.='Wir treffen uns']/following-sibling::br[position() < 3]
```

If you want to grab all 4 at the same time, you can combine the *before* and *after* XPath expressions above via `|`:

```
//h3[.='Wir treffen uns']/preceding-sibling::br[position() < 3]
|
//h3[.='Wir treffen uns']/following-sibling::br[position() < 3]
```

---

### Update 2

If you want the number range to include all nodes, not just `br` elements, when counting, then use this XPath:

```
//h3[.='Wir treffen uns']/preceding-sibling::node()[position() < 3][self::br]
|
//h3[.='Wir treffen uns']/following-sibling::node()[position() < 3][self::br]
```

This works by testing `node()` position first, then making sure that those nodes within range are `br` elements via `[self::br]`.  Be aware that all text nodes will count, even ones containing only whitespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have add a code snipped. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should think carefully about what you really want to select.  If I show you how to select 2 `br` elements before and after a `h3`, what will you do with them?  They have no content themselves.

Comment: hi and thanks! I would like to remove the <br> tags, because after and before the h3 tag there is now a padding, and the space with be is to large.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to show you how to grab 2 `br` elements *before* and 2 `br` elements *after* the targeted `h3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And Interesting! And when there are sometimes 3 or 4 `br`tags? Can I set easy <5 instead <3 ?

Comment: Yes, you can change the 3 if your requirements change.  Remember two points: (1) First position is 1, not 0 and (2) count *away* from the `h3`.

Comment: ok, i check it, but it removes all following `br` tags. What I search is a code to remove only `br`tags directly after the h3 tag. Not the br tags after a text after a h3 tag. `<h3>alright</h3><br><br>Text with important br-Tag<br>...

Comment: **Now you're changing the requirements (again).**  Last time: I've updated the answer to accomodate your latest request.  If this helps, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much! Great, your are the xpath-boss. It's actually possible to solve. It works, many thanks! And sorry for the changing requirements, I will try in the future the question to ask clearly. But its difficult for me, I have to take more time to build the question.

Comment: perfect answer bro